# UIStackView not reversed when viewDidLoad in RTL language

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, right-to-left, uistackview

I have a UIStackView in Storyboard with structure as below and want to scroll it to a specific button in viewDidLoad.

[image]

This is how I'm scrolling it.

`[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:button.frame animated:YES];`

The problem is, when setting system language to a RTL language (such as Arabic), the direction of UIStackView and button.frame are still left to right in viewDidLoad, so the scroll position is incorrect.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, frame setup is not completed in `viewDidLoad`.

Move that code to `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:button.frame animated:YES];
}
```